Why won't Django load my CSS file with my HTML?
I am new to building Django apps, and trying to add a simple CSS File to a simple HTML file for style points. I am not having any luck getting the CSS file to read into the HTML document on my web server. Can you please help me with this issue?
My directory looks similar to this:
web3/
├── home1/
│   ├── static/
│   │   └── home1/
│   │       └── style.css

where home1 is the app, and I have my template for HTML in the first home1 folder (ie. home1/template/home1/home.html)
Here is what I have in my html document:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Kirby is the greatest</title>
  
   
   <!-- Link the CSS file -->
   {% load static %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home1/style.css'%}">
 
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Great Job</h1>
  <h2>Proud</h2>
</body>


my views.py:
`# home1/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("you did it")

def home(request):
    return render(request,"home1/home.html")'


and the static portion of my settings.py:
`# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "home1/static",
]
# Define the directory where 'collectstatic' will place all static files for production
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
`




First step is to look at the webserver log and see if the css file is even being requested by the browser.

You have a typo in your syntax. There should be spaces between {% %} and everything within.

First thing that you have to do is to understand at what point it fails. Probably the most common thing is that your static files are not added to a urlpatterns of your project. You can do that in {settings_dir}/urls.py and add this:
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ... your URLconf goes here ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT), # Static files (that you create on development)
        static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # Media files (that are uploaded by users)
    ]

Notice, that they are under if settings.DEBUG condition. Usually, when you are deploying it to server it lays behind NGINX or Apache, which can reroute your "static file" requests and serve them more efficiently while not loading main server.
Django docs about static and media files
